# How to run library and integration tests only?

Tags: testing, rust, integration, rust-cargo

I have a project with a library and two executables. When I run `cargo test`, it runs five executables: the unit tests for the library and both executables, integration tests, and doc tests.

Since I have only library and integration tests, I get annoying output like:

```
running 0 tests                                                           
test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

I have tried to filter it with Cargo parameters but failed. If I use `--lib` then no integration tests are run. I didn't find a way to run integration tests only or to skip doc or executable tests.

Is there any way to run only integration and library unit tests?

Comment: That [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-02-running-tests.html#controlling-how-tests-are-run) seems useful for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution.

Package manifest file (Cargo.toml) must be modified like this:

```
[lib]
doctest = false

[[bin]]
test = false
```

Comment: the `lib` lines work for me, but the `[[bin]]` part throws an exception: `binary target bin.name is required`

Answer (score 0):

(since I can't format this in a comment...)

You need to specify your binary name (definitely if you have more than one):

```
[[bin]] 
name = "check_dir" 
test = false

[[bin]]
name = "other"
test = false
```